# How to replace string or hide string in url after mapping to controller from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am trying to hide or replace string in the `URL` after mapping to controller from view.

View

```
    <a href='@Url.Action("Product", "Index", new { prodID =@item.ProductID 
    })'>
```

Controller

```
      public ActionResult Product()
      {

        return View(model);
      }
```

Now I am getting this in URL like this `http://localhost:9210/Index/Product?prodID=1`
But I want `url` like this `http://localhost:9210/Index/Product/1`
So how can I do this? Please help

Comment: Then you have to have a route defined `/Product/{prodID}`, either in your route config or through attributes.

Comment: Yes,you right i want like this `http://localhost:9210/Index/Product/1

Comment: @CodeCaster how can i do this please tell me

Comment: @icon try the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass like this.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Product", "Index", new { id =@item.ProductID 
})'>
```

Probably becuase the parameter defined in the `route.config` file will be by the name `id` and not `prodID`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the route expected with the `Route` attribute.

```
[Route("Index/Product/{prodId}")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateStatus(int prodId)
{
}
```

Comment: Its showing red line blow `[Route` I have added route line above action result ` [Route("Index/Product/{prodID}")]
        public ActionResult Product(int prodID)`